# Fullcalendar event in timeGridWeek not render well angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm trying to work with fullCalendar in gridDayMonth view it's working good(Image attached) but in timeGridWeek the events not working like in the demo(Image attached), title & time not shown.

Please help.

HTML :

```
       <full-calendar #calendarApi
              [options]='calendarOptions'>
       </full-calendar>
```

Getting Data :

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.events = await this.getEvents();
    this.calendarApi.calendar.addEventSource(this.events);
  }
```

Configuration :

```
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    direction: 'rtl',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'next,prev today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    locale: heLocale,
    selectable: true,
    select: this.openModal.bind(this),
    eventAdd: this.handleEventAdd.bind(this),
  };
```

DayGridMonth
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9tnq.png)

Title & time missing
TimeGridWeek
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGvAy.png)

Comment: What does html look like? Or is that the HTML?  Also if you are waiting for any data, the Angular Render cycle already ran, which means it won't show anything in a Subscribe or Promise resolve.

Comment: HTML : 
 <full-calendar #calendarApi [options]='calendarOptions'></full-calendar>
And yes I'm waiting for data from db ,but if this is the case why in month it's working and in week is not?

Comment: I'm adding soure like this. 

    this.events = await this.getEvents();
    this.calendarApi.calendar.addEventSource(this.events);

Comment: Try this hide the <full-calendar> using *ngIf until after the data has arrived. Then show it.  Here's an article on that part https://dev.to/jwp/angular-why-doesn-t-my-data-show-up-4efm

Comment: The same issue... moving the getEvents method to afterViewInit for access the #calendar element buy still not working.

Comment: Hide the control until after the data arrives. Does that help? After the data gets there set it and change the show *ngIf ='show' to true followed by changeDetectorRef.detectchanges();

Comment: As we start working in monthView but not in weekView

Comment: Not working... :(

Comment: Show us what is in Options when calendar is displayed.

Comment: Inspect the element and play with the CSS styles and it shows up. 
The box of the event for half an hour is small and because that it was hidden. 
Tnx for the help buddy.